# split string into groups with given condition

Tags: java, algorithm

Given a String only made of only 2 letters a,b. Now the task is to split this string into exactly 3 groups such that the number of a's in each group must be same. Then find how many such groups are possible.

**Example:**

```
Input:
ababab

Possiblities:
ab ab ab

Output:
1 as we can create only 1 such group, with single a in each group
```

**Example:**

```
Input:
ababbabbaaba

Possiblities:

aba bbabba aba
abab babba aba
ababb abba aba

Output:3 
as we can create 3 such possible groups with 2 a's in each group.
```

Now I came across below code that is solving this task.

```
public static int findGroups(String input) {
    int numberOfAs = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        if (input.charAt(i) == 'a')
            numberOfAs++;
    }
    int n = input.length();
    if (numberOfAs == 0) {
        return (n - 1) * (n - 2) / 2;
    }

    if (numberOfAs % 3 != 0)
        return 0;

    int numberOfAsInAGroup = numberOfAs / 3;

    int lastAIn1stGroup = 0; // last occurrence of A in 1st group
    int firstAIn2ndGroup = 0; // 1st occurrence of A in 2nd group
    int lastAIn2ndGroup = 0; // last occurrence of A in 2nd group
    int firstAIn3rdGroup = 0; // 1st occurrence of A in 3rd group
    int aCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (input.charAt(i) == 'a') {
            aCount++;
            if (aCount == numberOfAsInAGroup) {
                lastAIn1stGroup = i;
            } else if (aCount == numberOfAsInAGroup + 1) {
                firstAIn2ndGroup = i;
            }
            if (aCount == 2 * numberOfAsInAGroup) {
                lastAIn2ndGroup = i;
            } else if (aCount == 2 * numberOfAsInAGroup + 1) {
                firstAIn3rdGroup = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    int betweenSecondAndFirstGroup = firstAIn2ndGroup - lastAIn1stGroup;
    int betweenThirdAndSecondGroup = firstAIn3rdGroup - lastAIn2ndGroup;

    return betweenSecondAndFirstGroup * betweenThirdAndSecondGroup;
}
```

This code is working perfectly finw without any errors. But I am trying to understand for past several days what formulas are being used in this code to solve this task.

### Part - 1:

```
    if (numberOfAs == 0) {
        return (n - 1) * (n - 2) / 2;
    }
```

After searching in google for several hrs I found the explanation here  - [number-of-ways-of-distributing-n-identical-objects-among-r-groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47345/number-of-ways-of-distributing-n-identical-objects-among-r-groups):

### Part - 2:

```
    int betweenSecondAndFirstGroup = firstAIn2ndGroup - lastAIn1stGroup;
    int betweenThirdAndSecondGroup = firstAIn3rdGroup - lastAIn2ndGroup;

    return betweenSecondAndFirstGroup * betweenThirdAndSecondGroup;
```

I am not able to understand this **part 2** formula, how this is solving the given problem, is there any explanation as mentioned for part 1.

Also just curious to know, is there any alternate version to solve this task without using formulas like this?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in linear time.

```
public class Main {

    public static int Nth_A_After(String s, int n, int index){
        for(int i = index + 1; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if(s.charAt(i) == 'a'){
                n--;
                if(n == 0) return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "ababab";

        int count = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) if(s.charAt(i) == 'a') count++;

        if(count % 3 != 0) {
            System.out.println("Impossible!");
            return;
        }

        int pos = count / 3;

        int firstEnd = Nth_A_After(s, pos, -1);
        int secondBegin = Nth_A_After(s, 1, firstEnd);
        int secondEnd = Nth_A_After(s, pos - 1, secondBegin);
        int thirdBegin = Nth_A_After(s, 1, secondEnd);

        int leftDif = secondBegin - firstEnd;
        int rightDif = thirdBegin - secondEnd;
        if(leftDif > 1) leftDif++;
        if(rightDif > 1) rightDif++;

        System.out.println(leftDif * rightDif);
    }
}
```

I guess there is a problem in your example `ababab`, since there is more than just one possibility:

```
1. a ba bab
2. a bab ab
3. ab a bab 
4. ab ab ab
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you're looking at is finding the boundary As of each group, then is counting the number of spaces the dividing line between the groups could go. This depends on the number of Bs separating the groups of As, since these don't affect the count.

The answer is the number of possible dividing lines on the left, times the number on the right.

```
AA|B|B|AABAA <-- in this example there are 3 on the left
AABBAA|B|AA <-- and 2 on the right
for a total of 6. 

AA|BBAA|BAA
AA|BBAAB|AA
AAB|BAA|BAA
AAB|BAAB|AA
AABB|AA|BAA
AABB|AAB|AA
```